# Xamarin Grid To Fit Entire Screen Error For Loop

Tags: c#, xamarin

I can't quite figure out what I'm missing here. Goal: Create a grid that is 5 by 5 using a for loop that fits column and rows to the entire screen (hence the `GridUnitType.Star`).However, I have tried everything I knew about building 2D arrays, but nothing seems to be working. Do these `Column` and `Row` `Definitions` work differently? What am I missing?

```
NewGrid.RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection();
NewGrid.ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection();


for (int i = 0; i < textToInt; i++)
{
  NewGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
  for (int j = 0; j < textToInt; j++)
  {
    NewGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
    NewGrid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "" + i },j,i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
            for (int i = 0; i < textToInt; i++)
            {
                NewGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
                NewGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
                for (int j = 0; j < textToInt; j++)
                {
                  
                    NewGrid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "" +j},i,j);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < textToInt; i++)
  {
    NewGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
 for (int j = 0; j < textToInt; j++)
 {
    NewGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
  }
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < textToInt; i++)
 {
 for (int j = 0; j < textToInt; j++)
  {
    NewGrid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "" + i },j,i);
  }
  }
```

Try this.